# Linq Query Always returns False and Failed to Fetch Data

Tags: linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf service into angular js application. I wrote linq query to check user information . If the is not null then query should catch the information and return true otherwise its should return false . **But the problem is its always returns false and catch values null**

Here is the linq Query .

```
 public bool CreateCurrentAccountCheck(Current_Account_Holder_Details current_Account_Details)
        {
          using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context =new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {

                var query = (from x in context.Current_Account_Holder_Details
                             where x.Account_Holder_First_Name == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_First_Name && x.Account_Holder_Last_Name == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_Last_Name
                             && x.Account_Holder_DOB == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_DOB && x.Account_Holder_House_No == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_House_No
                             && x.Account_Holder_Street_Name == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_Street_Name && x.Account_Holder_Post_Code == current_Account_Details.Account_Holder_Post_Code
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();
                if (query!=null)
                {
                    return true;

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the screen shot on debugging Mode .

[image]

Comment: There is no record according to the given predicate.

Comment: The record is exist in database but the problem is query always returns false no matter if I use the correct information

Comment: Are any values returned when you simplify the query, ex. only check on first and last name?

Comment: It's does not return the values . It's always returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear that there is no matched record with the where clauses. Also, you want to check the record and you should check it with using an unique id instead of other required or not required fields. It is the exact way to apply it. You should have some kind of unique `AccountDetailId` or other name which applies unique info for the records.

```
var query = (from x in context.Current_Account_Holder_Details
                             where x.AccountDetailId == current_Account_Details.AccountDetailId
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Without unique id the query will always returns false??